# How to download directory from Server using JSCH?

Tags: download, directory, jsch

i already use JSCH from List files, upload/download files, create dir etc.
But i have some problem while i want to download directory from Server and save it to destination directory. I use JFileChooser for save it.

How the process? Because if i use the process like file download it give IOException and null value :

```
Feb 24, 2013 9:22:05 PM com.ikbiz.filemanager.controller.ServerDataController download
SEVERE: null
java.io.IOException: error
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$2.read(ChannelSftp.java:1361)
...
...
```

Please help me :) Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Vector ls(String path)`](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#ls%28java.lang.String%29) method to list the files in the remote directory. Then you create a local directory with the same name [`mkdirs()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) and you loop over all remote files to download them.

I would do it like that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at 
https://github.com/xiaoerge/File-UI/blob/master/src/fileui/GUI.java#L364

private void get() ...

The logic is,
-1 If the entry is a file,  download it.

-2 If its a directory,  `mkdir` a correspondent directory on local system,
   `cd` into that directory both locally and remotely,  now `ls` the current
   remote directory, (no need to `ls` local because it is empty)

-3 Repeat step 1 and 2 on every `ls` entry you get from remote side.

-4 Eventually you will have `mkdir`(ed) all matching directories on your local side and downloaded all non directories.

-5 Remember to `cd` backup to the parent directory after you are done inside each sub directory.